# Python Optimize.minimize usage

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I have two questions concerning the usage of the optimize.minimize function,

is it correct to call it in the following way?

```
res2 = minimize(function,0.1,args=(0.1,0.1),method='Nelder-Mead',tol=0.0000005)
```

if the function has as first element a vector?

```
function(vect,a,b)
```

Second questions, are the "array" values coinciding with the values of the variables of the function minimum? If not how can I get them?
I get this output from the previous case and I don't know how to interpret the first three and the last lines:

```
final_simplex: (array([[153.11013672],
      [153.11013702]]), array([816.50936353, 816.50936353]))
          fun: 816.5093635275102
      message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
         nfev: 90
          nit: 43
       status: 0
      success: True
            x: array([153.11013672])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question 1: yes, it is correct to call it that way.

question 2: `x` is the resulting 'argmin', `fun` is `function(x, ...)` and `final_simplex` contains the last function arguments and corresponding function values evaluated during the last steps of the optimization algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much, at the moment the function is called with a size three vector and two scalars, why does it show four arguments?